# Enviar variavel para o layout no laravel4 com blade

Tags: php, laravel-4, mvc, laravel-blade

Galera estou com um problema aqui preciso enviar uma variavel para o meu layout, eu tentei assim:

No controller

```
$this->layout->page = 'Atendentes';
```

e no layout isso

```
@yield('page')
```

o problema é que eu preciso comparar essa variavel page dentro de um if que no caso é:

```
@if ( @yield('page') == 'Atendentes' )
    //do something
@endif
```

porém ele embaraça as tags do php, ele me retorna um erro com o código assim:

```
<?php if ( <?php echo $__env->yieldContent('page') == 'Atendentes' ); ?>: ?>
```

Comment: Tente `@if ($page == 'Atendentes' )`.

Comment: ele não encontra a variavel

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined variable: page

Comment: Ah, você está passando a variável pelo layout. Tente passar essa variável na chamada do View::make do seu método como array no segundo argumento: `View::make('path.do.view', [ 'page' => 'Atendentes'])`

Comment: então eu estou passando a variavel para o meu layout, se eu passar pela view ela vai só para a view não fica acessivel no layout

Answer (score 2):

Consegui usando o view::share no controller pra compartilhar uma variavel em todas as minhas views

```
   $page = 'Atendentes';
   View::share('page', $page);
```

Comment: `$this->layout->with('page' => 'Atendentes');` outra forma de obter o mesmo resultado